# Comparing a list of items with its class

Tags: java

So I'm making a game, and in this game the player has an inventory which has a list of items, and since there are different kinds of items I have a class for Items, Food Items, etc. and I want a button that says eat and that the button only renders if the item is a let's say food item I was wondering if there is a way to test to see if it's a Food Item out of the list, I know this question has been asked before but I found the answers a little vague, I have tried the obvious ways like instanceof (I realized after that its testing for the superclass) way but with no luck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That *really* depends on how you've implemented this inventory collection, and it also *really* depends on the hierarchy between your items and food items.  *Some* code here would make it straightforward to give you a clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myItem instanceof FoodItem){
// Print eat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach (and the one used by most MUDs) is to allow objects to supply their own commands (i.e. actions that can be taken on that object). Then, you could have an abstract superclass Food object which provided an 'eat' command and which was extended by all food items.

Take a look at [CoffeeMUD](http://www.coffeemud.org/) for an adventure game engine in Java.

Answer (score 0):

#### There are plenty of solutions here.

One solution is to have an abstract class called FoodItem , then inherit from it.
Then you can use

```
if (item instanceof FoodItem)
```

If you want an item to be able to belong to multiple groups, use an **Interface** instead.

Another solution is creating an enum of groups.
Then each object can declare it's type with a getter method.

```
public MyEnum getGroup();
```